# NSTableview column identifier

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableview`, in this table view I populate columns with `objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`.

I would like a column that is not populated. If I place a column with no identifier or an identifier that doesn't match a key I receive an error for not being key coding compliant.

Now what I have done to circumvent this is add a column with an identifier named 'skip', I check for this condition in my code with this...

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    Pizza* pizza  = [pizza objectAtIndex:row];


    NSString* identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"skip"]) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [pizza valueForKey:identifier];
}
```

I also have to reciprocate this in the `setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` as well.

It seems to work fine, but it seems like a bit of a hack.

Is there a better way to do this?

Furthermore, the reason I want empty columns is because I want to place objects such as buttons that don't belong to the array that the table view is referencing.

Thanks for you input!

Comment: It's not a hack. That's how it's done. You're supposed to check the column identifier to figure out what object value to return for it. You wanted to just pass that choice through to the `Pizza` object, but it's common for a view to have aspects that aren't embodied in the model and therefore the controller has to mediate. If you want, you could override `-valueForUndefinedKey:` in the `Pizza` class but, in my opinion, *that* would be a hack. By the way, once you have a check of the column identifier, you don't have to use "skip". You can check for an empty identifier as easily.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Looks like a good answer to me... Post it so that I can accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a hack. That's how it's done. You're supposed to check the column identifier to figure out what object value to return for it. You wanted to just pass that choice through to the Pizza object, but it's common for a view to have aspects that aren't embodied in the model and therefore the controller has to mediate. If you want, you could override -valueForUndefinedKey: in the Pizza class but, in my opinion, that would be a hack. By the way, once you have a check of the column identifier, you don't have to use "skip". You can check for an empty identifier as easily.